# Would this crystal radio circuit work?

Tags: radio, crystal, piezo, crystal-set

Would this crystal radio circuit, that I came across, work?

If it would not work, I would like to know which part of the circuit could be the likely cause and why.

[image]

The speaker shown is actually a homemade piezo electric earpiece.

Comment: That circuit is good - it *can* work. But satisfactory results depend on components...you'll want a long outdoor antenna, a good ground, a well-constructed inductor of appropriate inductance, a variable ~350pf capacitor. That home-made piezo earpiece may need further description - some of these piezo elements are not very sensitive.

Comment: Well I got a piezo element from a singing gift card and glued a little chamber that will direct sound to my ear, and that "chamber" is going in my ear like a headphone thing

Comment: Today there are many more AM radio stations than there was 70 years ago so the crystal radio today will probably pickup a few stations at the same time, because the circuit has only one tuned LC circuit. A REAL AM radio today has at least 5 tuned LC circuits.

Comment: That isn't a design; it's more of a block diagram using symbols to represent things as a learning aid. Plus, any picture you take from the web or another source requires a link back to the source of that image.

Comment: @Andyaka This was not taken from any other source I made it on https://www.circuit-diagram.org

Comment: Title says "this circuit that I designed", while the body says "the circuit that I found". Which is it? Don't take credit for designing something when you just found it on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few plausible reasons for your crystal radio not working.

1. There is no strong medium-wave AM radio station nearby.
2. The wire antenna length is insufficient. Having an antenna length of 50' - 150' would help.
3. The 'earth' connection is not good enough. An underground metallic water pipe or electrical service ground should serve the purpose.
4. The tuned circuit is not resonant across the medium wave band. A coil inductance of 240 μH and a variable capacitance of 0 - 365 pF would ensure resonance across the band.
5. A silicon diode (Vf = 0.7 V) has been used instead of a germanium or a schottky diode (Vf = 0.2 V).
6. The home-made piezo-electric earpiece is not good enough. A good piezo-electric earpiece or balanced armature headphones will make a big difference.

Comment: "*There is no strong medium-wave AM radio station nearby.*" — It doesn't have to be nearby.  I made a similar setup as a teenager (the coil was telephone wire wrapped around a toilet paper tube, and the capacitor was rolled up waxed paper and aluminum foil), and could easily get WRVA at night, nearly a 1000 km away.

Comment: I agree, Ray, but having a station nearby is a big help for a newbie learning the ropes of building a crystal radio.